# Reading all the values (int)of a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

I want to read all the information from a randomaccessfile containing integers, with 1 integer a line. eg. It seems to be a problem with my "reading" code.
File Contents:

```
1
3
5
72
0
```

My current code gives me an EOFException error and the data that I take in is not correct eg 1 is printed as 857222 etc.
Output:

```
822751754
856306698
805975306
856306186
java.io.EOFException
822751754


while((tmp = randomFile.readInt()) != -1){
  System.out.println(tmp)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readInt()` and "1 integer a line" don't match.

Either you have a binary file containing bytes that can be read using `readInt()` (which reads always four bytes for an integer), or you have lines of text where each line contains a readable representation of integer values (which seems to be your case).

To read lines of text containing integer values, you have to rewrite your code like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = randomFile.readLine()) != null) {
    int tmp = Integer.parseInt(line);
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_randomaccessfile.htm) gets to the end of a file, [`.nextInt()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/randomaccessfile_readint.htm) won't return `-1`, it will throw an `EOFException`. Therefore you should do something like this:

```java
while(true){
   try{
      tmp = randomFile.readInt()
      System.out.println(tmp)
   }catch(EOFException e){
      break;
   }
}
```